# Mixed signed assemblies in 1 VS solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, architecture, assemblies, signed

Hey, currently I am trying to run a project (Noizwaves.Client) which has a dependency (as a project reference) to a signed class library (Noizwaves.Core). Noizwaves.Core has it's assembly version set to 2.0.*. I have both of these projects within the same VS2008 solution file. Noizwaves.Client is set as the default startup project.

All projects (and the solution) build fine in VS, but when I run Noizwaves.Client, I get this following exception:

Could not load file or assembly 'Noizwaves.Core, Version=2.0.3378.15610, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bed7327d8103b148' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

When i look in the debug directory for Noizwaves.Client, I can see the version of Noizwaves.Core is 2.0.3378.15613.

I think the build settings/order of the projects is to blame in VS2008. Currently the settings are all set to default.

Does anyone have a fix to this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Noizwaves.Client is possibly loading Noizwaves.Core from different location.
Is Noizwaves.Core in GAC ? In some folder under Visual Studio (e.g C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies)

If that doensn't help you could try the following:

Setup registry like this (note: I suggest you make a copy of original values so you can revert to original state):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion]
"ForceLog"=dword:00000001
"LogFailures"=dword:00000001
"LogPath"="C:\\Temp\\FusionLog"
```

And create a folder C:/Temp/FusionLog.

Fusion is part of .NET framework that is responsible for finding/loading assemblies.

After this change you will find a bunch of log files in that folder for all .NET apps.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of reference does the Client project have on the Core DLL?  Is it a file reference, or a project reference?  Try removing the reference and re-adding it as a project reference.

Comment: Hey, i've edited the description to include the reference as a project reference.